# GUI built with PyQt5 and compile by pyinstaller not working

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, python-3.8

When I try to compile a simple GUI the compiled .exe file would open an empty command window
for a few seconds and shuts down automatically.

I've tried using --hidden-import=sip and anything else I could find online
but cannot get it working or figure out why it isn't working properly.

Since, I cannot get any error messages, I include the GUI code below.

Thanks in advance!

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import os, os.path
import wget
import glob

from remove_empty import removeEmptyFolders

form_class = uic.loadUiType('light_gui.ui')[0]


class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.dir_open.clicked.connect(self.pick_dir)
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.doong_light)



    def pick_dir(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)
        self.down_path.setText('%s\\' % os.path.normpath(fname)) # os.path.normpath(path) --> Change "/" to "\" on Windows OS
        return(fname)



    def doong_light(self):
        def one_page_contents(target_page):
            contents = target_page.html.find('img')
            vid_contents = target_page.html.find('video')

            attached = []
            others = []

            for content in contents:
                if 'attach' in content.attrs['src']:
                    # print(content.attrs['src'][0])
                    # if content.attrs['src'][0] == '/files':
                    #     print('https://twicenest.com' + content.attrs['src'])
                    #     attached.append('https://twicenest.com' + content.attrs['src'])
                    # else:
                    #     attached.append(content.attrs['src'])
                    # attached.append(content.attrs['src'])
                    attached.append(str(content.attrs['src']))

                elif 'kakao' in content.attrs['src']:
                    others.append(content.attrs['src'])
                elif 'blogspot' in content.attrs['src']:
                    others.append(content.attrs['src'])
                try:
                    if '이미지' in content.attrs['alt']:
                        others.append(str(content.attrs['src']).split('?')[0] + '.jpg')
                except:
                    pass

            for content in vid_contents:
                if 'attach' in content.attrs['src']:
                    # if content.attrs['src'][0] == '/files':
                    #     attached.append('https://twicenest.com' + content.attrs['src'])
                    # else:
                    #     attached.append(content.attrs['src'])
                    # attached.append(content.attrs['src'])
                    attached.append(str(content.attrs['src']))

                elif 'kakao' in content.attrs['src']:
                    others.append(content.attrs['src'])
                elif 'blogspot' in content.attrs['src']:
                    others.append(content.attrs['src'])
                try:
                    if '비디오' in content.attrs['alt']:
                        others.append(str(content.attrs['src']).split('?')[0] + '.mp4')
                except:
                    pass

            return attached, others

        def alphanumeric(title):

            kill_list = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
            no_punct = ''

            for s in title:
                if s not in kill_list:
                    no_punct += s
            post_title = no_punct

            if len(post_title) >= 30:
                post_title = ('%.30s' % post_title)
                post_title = post_title.strip()

            return post_title

        def contents_download(attached, dst, post_title, error, title_num, choice):
            img_num = 1
            base_url = 'https://www.twicenest.com'
            base_url = str(base_url)

            for i in range(len(attached)):
                # print(content.attrs['src'][0])
                # if content.attrs['src'][0] == '/':
                #     print('https://twicenest.com' + content.attrs['src'])
                #     attached.append('https://twicenest.com' + content.attrs['src'])
                # else:
                #     attached.append(content.attrs['src'])
                # attached.append(content.attrs['src'])
                if attached[i][0] == '/':
                    img_url = base_url + attached[i]

                else:
                    img_url = attached[i]
                ### 글 하나에 있는 사진/영상 한폴더로 다운로드하기 위해 폴더 만들기###

                if choice == 2:

                    if not os.path.exists(dst + str(title_num) + '_' + str(post_title)):
                        print('폴더 만들기')
                        os.mkdir(dst + str(title_num) + '_' + str(post_title))

                    try:
                        wget.download(img_url, dst + str(title_num) + '_' + str(post_title) + '\\')

                    except:
                        error[post_title] = img_url
                        pass
                    file_list = glob.glob((dst + str(title_num) + '_' + str(post_title) + '\\*'))
                    if len(file_list) != 0:
                        latest_file = max(file_list, key=os.path.getctime)
                        if latest_file.split('.')[-1] == 'wget':
                            os.rename(latest_file,
                                      dst + str(title_num) + '_' + str(post_title) + '\\' + str(img_num) + str(
                                          post_title) + '.' + img_url.split('.')[-1])
                        else:
                            try:
                                os.rename(latest_file,
                                          dst + str(title_num) + '_' + str(post_title) + '\\' + str(img_num) + str(
                                              post_title) + '.' + img_url.split('.')[-1])
                            except:
                                pass

                        # file_name = latest_file.split('\\')[-1]

                        print(post_title + ' 다운 시작' + ' ' + str(img_num))
                        img_num += 1

                if choice == 1:
                    ### 다운 목표 페이지에 있는 모든 첨부 한폴더에 저장
                    try:
                        print(post_title + ' 다운 시작' + ' ' + str(img_num))
                        # print(img_url)
                        wget.download(img_url, dst)
                    except:
                        error[post_title] = img_url
                        pass
                    file_list = glob.glob((dst + '*'))
                    if len(file_list) >= 1:
                        latest_file = max(file_list, key=os.path.getctime)
                        # file_name = latest_file.split('\\')[-1]
                        if latest_file.split('.')[-1] == 'wget':
                            os.rename(latest_file, dst + str(img_num) + str(post_title) + '.' + img_url.split('.')[-1])
                        else:
                            try:
                                os.rename(latest_file,
                                          dst + str(post_title) + '_' +
                                          latest_file.split('.')[-2].split('\\')[-1] + str(img_num) + '.' +
                                          latest_file.split('.')[-1])
                            except:
                                pass

                    img_num += 1

            for key in error:
                error_path = key.strip()
                if not os.path.exists(dst + error_path):
                    os.mkdir(dst + error_path)
                try:
                    wget.download(error[key], dst + error_path)
                except:
                    # print(error[key])
                    pass

            title_num += 1

        # dst = input('다운 받을 경로 어디? : ')
        dst = str(self.down_path.text())

        print('')
        # url = input('다운 받을 페이지 url : ')
        url = str(self.target_url.text())
        session = HTMLSession()
        target_page = session.get(url)

        title = target_page.html.find('meta')[6].attrs['content']
        post_title = alphanumeric(title)

        error = dict()
        attached, others = one_page_contents(target_page)
        # print(attached, others)

        contents_download(attached, dst, post_title, error, 1, 1)
        contents_download(others, dst, post_title, error, 1, 1)
        removeEmptyFolders(dst)

        return attached, others

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(389, 182)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 151, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 333, 82))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.target_url = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.target_url.setObjectName("target_url")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.target_url, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.down_path = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.down_path.setObjectName("down_path")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.down_path, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.dir_open = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.dir_open.setObjectName("dir_open")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dir_open, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.start_btn.setObjectName("start_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.start_btn, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 389, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "둥닷 다운로더 라이트 v1.0"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "다운 받을 URL : "))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "다운 받을 폴더 : "))
        self.dir_open.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.start_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GO!"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    light_gui = Ui_MainWindow()
    light_gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you have problems with my solution then you should point out in the comments, you should not create new questions as they will be closed as duplicates of this question. Please read [ask], [answer] and review the [tour]